# where to place .jks file in springapp and what relative path to provide in cxf.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cxf, mutual-authentication

I have a spring app that acts as a client for the mutual authentication (send a request to a server that is configured for mutual authentication). In the client springapp, I have a cxf.xml file in the src/main/resources. The file gets picked up correctly. However the reference to .jks file does not seem to work

My cxf.xml file has a conduit defined as:

```
<http:tlsClientParameters>
  <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="xxxx">
    <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="xxxx"
                  file="xyz.jks"/>
  </sec:keyManagers>
</http:tlsClientParameters>

<http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive"/>
```

I always get an error that says file cannot be found. 
Can someone help me figure where I can place this .jks file in my spring app and the relative path I can provide in the cxf.xml httpconduit above so it pick the xyz.jks file correctly?

Comment: As far as I know, don't you have to configure the application server like Tomcat to include the JKS file location and its password. In the webapp, you have to mention which URL's use https.

Comment: did you try to use the "resource" attribute instead of the "file" attribute? it should help you to reference a resource (a file in your case) in your classpath

Answer (score 3):

the CXF Xml-schema have a **resource** attribute defined on the *sec:keyStore* element which makes it possible to reference a keystore's file (JKS, PKCS12 etc ...) from the classpath. It is mutually exclusive with the *file* attribute (either one of the *resource* or *file* attribute may be present, but not both of them)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "resource" attribute instead of "file" attribute to address relatively:

```
<http:tlsClientParameters>
  <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="xxxx">
    <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="xxxx" resource="xyz.jks"/>  
  </sec:keyManagers>
</http:tlsClientParameters>
<http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive"/>
```